# Translation of plugin Upload button

Tags: plugin-development

I want to translate "Upload an image" by using `_()`, `_e()`. It does not work for me. I tried `value= _e( 'Upload an image')` but did not work out.

```
function logo_image() {
 $options = get_option('plugin_options');
      echo"<input type='text'  class='regular-text text-upload' name='plugin_options[logo_image]' value='{$options['logo_image']}'/>";
      echo "<input type='button' class='button button-upload' value='Upload an image'/>";
      echo"<img style='max-width: 200px; display: block;' src='{$options['logo_image']}' class='preview-upload'/>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `esc_attr__()` to translate and escape strings for HTML attributes:

```
$button_text = esc_attr__( 'Upload an image', 'your_text_domain' );

echo "<input type='button' class='button button-upload' value='$button_text' />";
```